# time conversion fails on Linux

Tags: c++11

ALL,

```
pcap_pkthdr pkthdr;
time_t nowtime = pkthdr->ts.tv_sec;
char tmbuf[64];
struct tm *nowtm = localtime( nowtime );
strftime( tmbuf, sizeof( tmbuf ), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", nowtm );
```

Trying to compile this code using gcc with C++11, I am getting:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'time_t {aka long int}' to 'const time_t* {aka const long int*}' [-fpermissive]
                         struct tm *nowtm = localtime( nowtime );
                                                               ^
```

What is wrong? Why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localtime` takes a pointer to `time_t`, you passed the `time_t` itself. Change it to:

```
struct tm *nowtm = localtime( &nowtime );
                           // ^ Takes address of nowtime
```